# Why the output is not a string

Tags: php

I tried many time, but I still don't understand why the output is not a string, anything wrong ? help me check it. The final output should be a uppercase name string

```
<html>
<p>
<?php
// Create an array and push on the names
// of your closest family and friends
$name = array();
array_push($name,"Mike");
array_push($name,"Jane");
array_push($name,"Jack");
array_push($name,"Nike");
array_push($name,"Ash");
array_push($name,"Chris");
array_push($name,"Zark");




// Sort the list
sort($name);
join(",",$name);


// Randomly select a winner!
$random = count($name,rand(0,7));
// Print the winner's name in ALL CAPS
$winner = strtoupper($random);
print($winner);
?>
</p>
</html>
```

Comment: `$random = count($name,rand(0,7));` what are you trying to do here? `$random = $name[rand(0, count($name))];` is probably what you're after. Also, remove the `join(',', $name)` line as it does nothing.

Comment: What's the point of `$name = array();` followed by all those `array_push` calls? why not `$name = array('Name 1', 'Name 2',...);` and even so: why not `$name[] = 'add name';`? that at least avoids a function call

Answer (score 11):

```
$random = count($name,rand(0,7));
```

This line assigns the count of elements in `$name`.  I don't know what else you expected to get back other than a number here.

What you really want:

```
echo strtoupper($name[array_rand($name)]);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

---

Other Notes:

- Your call to `join()` doesn't do anything useful since you're not doing anything with the return value.
- Your call to `sort` is pointless if you're just picking a random entry later.
- Pick a plural name for your array names so you know they are arrays.  `$names` instead of `$name`.
- If you know all of the array elements ahead of time, no need for `array_push()`, just use an array literal:  `array('Mike', 'Jane', /* etc */)`
- If you're outputting data into the context of HTML, always use `htmlspecialchars()` to make sure any reserved characters are escaped properly.  This isn't a problem with the code you literally have here, but will be as soon as you want to output `<` or `"`.

Comment: Was literally typing this up almost word for word.

Comment: Looks like you did know what they expected to get back after all.

Comment: Everytime I read about array_rand and remember how much times I've done the same task manually http://imgur.com/myewpvP

Comment: This (your answer) is going to cut down on a LOT of code; *good answer.*